# Calling a nested function in xargs (on MacOS)

Tags: bash, zsh

I have the following setup:

```
#!/bin/bash

function outer() {
  function inner() {
    ...
  }

  ... | xargs -L1 inner

}
```

So, I want to call `inner` for each of the lines that are generated in `outer` and call the function from an interactive shell. How would I do that?

I've tried exporting the `inner` function (from within `outer`) but that has no effect as I get 'no such file or directory'.

Note that `inner` calls `xargs` too, so for each output piped from `outer` to `inner` there will multiple executions (in case that makes a difference).

Comment: It's _not_ a duplicate because the accepted answer for the suggested duplicate question does not work, as explained.

Comment: Instead of using xargs, pipe to a while loop. It can do while read line to read one line at a time and then run inner "$line". Zsh might work better if you want side effects on the shell because it runs the left of pipelines in a subshell rather than the right.